# Uniqueness of vertex optimal solution in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra

When we consider a linear programming of the following form:
$$\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \min_{x} 
    \quad & { c^Tx} \\ 
    \textrm{subject to} 
    \quad & x\in P \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$
where $P=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:a_i^Tx\leq b_i,~~\forall i=1,2,...,m\}$ denotes a non–empty polyhedron. Suppose we rule out the possibility of the optimal value being $-\infty$. Then we must have an optimal solution on the vertex.

I wanna ask: **if we've checked ALL the vertices, and we know there is only one vertex attains the optimal value** (aka, other vertices all give strictly higher objective function values). **Can we say that the optimal solution is unique given these said?**

Or, what further assumptions are needed if we want the statement above is true?

Comment: Consider $\min \{ y  | x \ge 0, y \ge 0 \}$, then the solution $0$ is attained at any $(x,0)$ for $x \ge 0$ but only $(0,0)$ is a vertex.

Comment: Very good point. @copper.hat

Comment: It is sort of a degenerate example. If the polyhedron was compact then the answer is yes.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you provide me some resource on that? I wanna find a proof but I did not manage to.

Comment: If by polyhedron you mean bounded, then you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P$ is non empty & compact (equivalently, contains no half lines) then the result is true.

The key results are (i) that a compact convex set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is equal to the convex hull of its extreme points (see Corollary 18.5.1 in Rockafellar, "Convex Analysis", cf. Krein Millman) and (ii) the vertices of a polyhedron are the same as the extreme points (this is not immediate, but straightforward, but I can't find the result in any texts at hand).

Then, if $E$ are the extreme points of $E$ we have
$\min_{ x \in P} c^T x = \min_{ x \in \operatorname{co} E} c^T x = \min_{ x \in E} c^T x$.

If $\arg \min_{x \in E} c^Tx$
is a singleton, then so is
$\arg \min_{ x \in P} c^Tx$
(otherwise we get a straightforward contradiction). In particular, the solution is unique.

I found a pdf [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Enickhar/W13/Scribe/Lecture3Scribe.pdf) that shows the equivalence of extreme points, vertices & basic feasible solutions for a polyhedron.
Also see Misha Lavrov's [notes](https://facultyweb.kennesaw.edu/mlavrov/courses/lp/lecture9.pdf).

Comment: For the equivalency between vertices and extreme points, on the principle that any citation is better than none, I have a proof [in my lecture notes](https://facultyweb.kennesaw.edu/mlavrov/courses/lp/lecture9.pdf).

Comment: @MishaLavrov THanks, I added a link to the answer. I like your Lego Escher stairs!